# Uploading video to YouTube by emailing to mobile upload address?

Tags: youtube

YouTube has this feature of upload videos to account by emailing them to your *mobile upload address* like `stxxxxwiicv@m.youtube.com`.I am using this feature to upload videos to my account.

I can set the **Title** and **description** of the video while emailing, for this I just need to specify `Email Subject for video Title` and `Email message for video description`.

My problem is that I would like to set the `keywords field` of the video as well while emailing the video.

I am unable to find any way to specify the Keywords for mobile uploads. If there is any official link for all this information, then please provide me with it.

Answer (score 1):

As of now, this is not possible. But, you can always go to the feedback part of YouTube's website and leave a suggestion.